# Unable to get response from keycloak openid-configuration URL(https) from angular 7 application with angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, ssl, keycloak, openid-connect

I am using keycloak as SSO for my angular 7 application which is using angular-oauth2-oidc to connect with keycloak for authentication.When I am trying the URL(**http://ip:4200**) for the first time, keycloak login page is not coming but I am getting errors in console.
[image]

but when I try to open https://IP:8443/auth/realms/apiman/.well-known/openid-configuration in the browser I get the following page:
[image]

If i click on **continue to** link and open **http://ip:4200** again then it will open up the keycloak login page.(After this it wont give me any error and successfully gets the data back from the openid-configuration url mentioned above) How can I solve this ? Is there anything to do with HTTP call from angular application to service having self signed certificate?
Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: How did you setup HTTPS certificates on Keycloak? Have you done anything manually? Seems your Keycloak is setup with an invalid/untrustable certificate.

Comment: I have not done any setup for HTTPS certificate. I am using keycloak as is from the download section [keycloak download](https://www.keycloak.org/downloads). Do we need to provide different certificate when we download and run keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is nothing to do with your Keycloak setup. If you've not changed anything on Keycloak/WildFly regarding the SSL, then your WildFly is just using the default self-signed certificate.

So as long as you're on dev environment, you can just use the HTTP for your tests. But for production, you should either setup the SSL on your reverse proxy/gateway that receives incoming calls or if the Keycloak server itself receives requests directly, you should follow the WildFly documentation about how to setup valid certificate on your WildFly server. Here are some links that maybe helpful:

- [How to configure SSL/HTTPS on WildFly](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/complete-tutorial-for-configuring-ssl-https-on-wildfly)
- [Setup SSL/HTTPS on JBoss Wildfly Application Server](https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-ssl-https-on-jboss-wildfly-application-server-fde6288a0f40)